Rxjs timer observable not emit whatsoever
I have this chain of operators like below, after planDetailComplete$ subject emit I will start a timer. Every 20 mins will start re-calling the API to getLockData
    this.detailService
        .getPlanSummary()
        .pipe(
          switchMap((data) => {
            // do something here
            return this.detailService.getLockData(this.somePk)
            );
          }),
        switchMap((lockData: LockDTO) => {
          // do something here and emit the planDetailComplete$.next()

          // listen to the planDetailComplete$ to emit and then:
          return this.detailService.planDetailComplete$.asObservable().pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
              console.log('start expire time')
              return this.expireTimeIntervalHandler(lockData);
            })
          );
        }),
        finalize(() => {
        // console.log('final')
          this._loadingService.hide();
        }),
        switchMap(() => {
         // this one doesn't get to run whatsoever
         // console.log('re get lock')
          return this.detailService.getLockData(this.studyPk);
        }),
      )
      .subscribe(),

the expireTimeInterval return an timer observable that emits every 20 minutes:
private expireTimeIntervalHandler = (lockData: LockDTO) => {
// calculate the schedule to recall the lock
    this._expireTime = lockData.expiration!;
    let lockScheduler =
      this._momentService.dateToTimestamp(this._expireTime, true) -
      this._momentService.dateToTimestamp(new Date().toUTCString(), true);

    return timer(0, lockScheduler * 1000).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.detailService.getStatusAddUpdateBaselineComplete().
pipe(tap(() => console.log('emit takeUntil'))),
    );  
}

I have checked and made sure that getStatusAddUpdateBaselineComplete never emit to stop the timer by adding the tap operators to debug, the log emit takeuntil never show at all.
The issue right now is the last switchMap in the chain operators never get to run, console only shows two logs that arestart expire time and final, I think it has something to do with the timer but can't wrap my head around why. Apologize for any confusion and thanks in advance for helping out

Always keep the trigger that starts the observable stream at the root of the subscribe.
Then, the takeUntil does not have a pipe operation. So it should be just a operator.
return timer(0, 2000).pipe(
  takeUntil(getStatusAddUpdateBaselineComplete$),
  tap(() => console.log('emit takeUntil'))
);

Full Code:
import './style.css';

import { of, switchMap, finalize, Subject, timer, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const getStatusAddUpdateBaselineComplete$ = new Subject();
const planDetailComplete$ = new Subject();

planDetailComplete$
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      of(true).pipe(
        switchMap((data: any) => {
          // do something here
          return of({});
        }),
        switchMap((lockData: any) => {
          // do something here and emit the planDetailComplete$.next()

          // listen to the planDetailComplete$ to emit and then:
          return expireTimeIntervalHandler(lockData).pipe();
        })
      )
    ),
    finalize(() => {
      console.log('final');
      // this._loadingService.hide();
    }),
    switchMap(() => {
      // this one doesn't get to run whatsoever
      console.log('re get lock');
      return of('re lock');
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (data: any) => console.log(data),
    error: (e: any) => console.log(e),
  });

const expireTimeIntervalHandler = (lockData: any) => {
  // calculate the schedule to recall the lock
  // this._expireTime = lockData.expiration!;
  // let lockScheduler =
  //   this._momentService.dateToTimestamp(this._expireTime, true) -
  //   this._momentService.dateToTimestamp(new Date().toUTCString(), true);

  return timer(0, 2000).pipe(
    takeUntil(getStatusAddUpdateBaselineComplete$),
    tap(() => console.log('emit takeUntil'))
  );
};

//trigger the event
planDetailComplete$.next('asdf');

setTimeout(() => {
  getStatusAddUpdateBaselineComplete$.next('close');
}, 5000);

Please use this working example and substitute your code.
Stackblitz Demo

I found out the issue, turned out it has nothing to do with observable chain. The issue was that some dev was adding an ngIf condition to manually destroy my component on parent component template, thus removing the timer subscription.
